# While doing Cross Cluster Replication between OpenSearch domains Getting Error transport_exception [][[x.x.x.x]:9300] general node connection failure

Tags: amazon-opensearch

"error"
"root_cause"
"type" : "transport_exception",
"reason" : "handshake failed because connection reset"
"type" : "connect_transport_exception",
"reason" : "[][[x.x.x.x]:9300] general node connection failure",
"caused_by" : {
"type" : "transport_exception",
"reason" : "handshake failed because connection reset"

Answer (score 0):

Could be a problem on AWS Side. Try to trigger Blue/green deployment on  both of your clusters, and apply latest patches for your version of OpenSearch.